# How can I tell if my Time Machine backup is encrypted?

Tags: time-machine, encryption

Is there a method to determine if a Time Machine backup disk is already encrypted?

Comment: Try to Mount its sparsebundle on a different Machine.

Answer (score 12):

I thought I'll add to the subject since I was looking for this info recently.

It actually shows just above the progress bar if the backup is encrypted during the backup process.

I'm pretty sure this was there since Maverick.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is a little round-a-bout but, without dropping to Terminal or anything more technical, will let you determine the encrypted state of the volume.

1. Open System Preferences
2. Choose Time Machine
3. Click "Select Disk..."
4. Highlight the current disk listed under Backup Disks
   [image: Backup Disks & Available Disks Menu]
5. Click "Remove Disk" button. This is NOT destructive. You are just un-associating the disk momentarily.
6. Click "Stop Using Disk"
7. Click "Select Backup Disk"
8. Select the same disk you just Removed ("Data" in my screen shot)
9. Select "Encrypt backups"
10. Click "Use Disk"
11. Authorize as prompted
12. If the disk is not encrypted you will see a dialog like the following [image: Dialog box when trying to use a non-encrypted volume as an encrypted Time Machine backup]
13. Choose "Use Unencrypted" to resume using the same volume unencrypted or "Erase Existing Backup" to create a fresh, encrypted backup.

Comment: My backups *were* already encrypted and, for me, prior to Step 9, the checkbox was already selected. And, as per Bart C's answer, if you start a Time Machine backup it'll say "encrypted" after the disk free space summary.